# Getting bash: python command not found error even though I am using zsh shell in my macOS

Tags: python, bash, cmake, zsh, macos-ventura

I am trying to build and install this [software](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenRV/)
So, I did these steps

```
# recursive repo cloning
git clone --recursive https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenRV.git
# sourcing there scripts
source rvcmds.sh
# configure
cmake -B_build -H. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DRV_DEPS_QT5_LOCATION=/Users/macos/Qt/5.15.2/clang_64
# building
cmake --build _build --config Release -v --target main_executable
```

now during build I get this error

```
OpenGL descriptors
--------------------------------------------------------------------
rm -rf extensions/gl
cp -r glfixes/gl/specs/ANGLE OpenGL-Registry/extensions
cp -r glfixes/gl/specs/REGAL OpenGL-Registry/extensions
bin/update_ext.sh extensions/gl OpenGL-Registry/extensions blacklist
--------------------------------------------------------------------
WGL descriptors
--------------------------------------------------------------------
rm -f extensions/gl/WGL_*
python bin/parse_xml.py OpenGL-Registry/xml/wgl.xml --api wgl --extensions extensions/gl
bash: python: command not found
make[4]: *** [extensions/gl/.dummy] Error 127
make[3]: *** [cmake/dependencies/RV_DEPS_GLEW-prefix/src/RV_DEPS_GLEW-stamp/RV_DEPS_GLEW-configure] Error 2
make[2]: *** [cmake/dependencies/CMakeFiles/RV_DEPS_GLEW.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main_executable.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [main_executable] Error 2
```

so according to the error I don't have python as it says python command not found, so what I did in my .zprofile I setup the alias like this `alias python="python3"`
when I do `python --version` I get same result as `python3 --version`
but since the cmake is running in bash shell (for some unknown reason) I get the error.

I even tried to change my default shell to bash and add the alias there, but still cmake gives error.

I am not sure how to fix this, if anyone has any idea regarding this, really appreciated .

Comment: *You* may use zsh for your interactive work, but *make* obviously uses bash. AFIK, make is normally using `sh` by default, but this can be configured, and in any case your bash is using `bash`.  I've never seen a _make_  which would use zsh by default. bash is not necessarily bad, except in the very unlikely case, that someone wants to use  zsh commands explicitly in the makefile.

Comment: Therefore you must make sure, that `bash` finds your `python3`. This means in the context of a Makefile, that an executable command of this name is present in your PATH. Alternatively, you can provide in your Makefile the absolute path to python3 explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest fix that I can think of is to create a symlink of your python3 executable, in the same folder, and name it python.

You can do this by running:

```bash
ln -s $(which python3) $(dirname $(which python3))/python
```

Comment: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)